# Get click info on ASP MapControl

Tags: asp.net, dictionary

I am using ASP.NET and MapXtreme. How do I get information about a mouse click on a MapComtrol?

Answer (score -1):

you can get a pretty good idea from the infotool example in the mapxtreme folder, there you will find a customcommand.js an a infotool.js there you make an ajax call to get the information from a point in the map.

cheers